# Difference between validateProperties() and invalidateProperties()

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

Can any one tell me about 
what is the Difference between `validateProperties()` and `invalidateProperties()` ?

Comment: Please search online for the answer before posting.

Comment: @J_A_X : I had searched but i cant get clear idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[invalidateProperties](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#invalidateProperties%28%29):

> Marks a component so that its commitProperties() method gets called
>   during a later screen update.
>
> Invalidation is a useful mechanism for eliminating duplicate work by
>   delaying processing of changes to a component until a later screen
>   update. For example, if you want to change the text color and size, it
>   would be wasteful to update the color immediately after you change it
>   and then update the size when it gets set. It is more efficient to
>   change both properties and then render the text with its new size and
>   color once.
>
> Invalidation methods rarely get called. In general, setting a property
>   on a component automatically calls the appropriate invalidation
>   method.

[validateProperties](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#validateProperties()):

> Used by layout logic to validate the properties of a component by
>   calling the commitProperties() method. In general, subclassers should
>   override the commitProperties() method and not this method.

Essentially, validate calls commitProperties directly while invalidate waits for the next frame to do it.  Always use invalidate.

Answer (score 1):

From: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/IInvalidating.html#invalidateProperties%28%29

### invalidateProperties()

```
public function invalidateProperties():void
```

Language Version:   ActionScript 3.0

Product Version:    Flex 3

Runtime Versions:   Flash Player 9, AIR 1.1

Calling this method results in a call to the component's `validateProperties()` method before the display list is ***rendered***.