# The property still has the old value in validateProperties

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, itemrenderer

I have a custom renderer (inherits from `AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer`), and I'm overriding `validateProperties` and using the value of the `width` property, but I'm getting the old value every time! Isn't `validateProperties` supposed to execute after the properties were committed (I'm calling super)? Here's my code:

```
public override function validateProperties():void
{
    super.validateProperties();
    if ((AdvancedDataGrid(listData.owner).columns[listData.columnIndex].
            showDataTips)&&(textWidth>width))
        toolTip=listData.label;
    else toolTip=null;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185594/difference-between-validateproperties-and-invalidateproperties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The trick is to use `validateSize` for the `width` property. `validateProperties` is for properties that don't belong to any of the other groups for which there's a dedicated `validateX` function (such as `validateSize`, `validateList`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

you should do this in the data setter for your item renderer:

```
public override function set data(val:Object):void{
    super.data=val;
    if ((AdvancedDataGrid(listData.owner).columns[listData.columnIndex].
                showDataTips)&&(textWidth>width))
            toolTip=listData.label;
        else toolTip=null;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to override width setter or to handle "textFieldWidthChange" event.